# Shortcode for button counter

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, button

I just wanted to create a shortcode to count the number of times a button is pressed and i have this code in my function.php file.

```
function btn_cntr_shortcode(){

'<input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />

<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>'

'<script type="text/javascript">'
  var $count = 0;
  var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
  var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

  button.onclick = function(){
    $count++;
    display.innerHTML = $count;
  }
'</script>'
return $count;

}
add_shortcode('button-counter','btn_cntr_shortcode');
```

But am getting the following error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`'<script type="text/javascript`' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home1/election/public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php on line 4645

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this PHP? It looks like PHP and JavaScript had a baby with every genetic defect in the book...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
function btn_cntr_shortcode(){

$output= '<input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />
          <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = 0;
            var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
            var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

           button.onclick = function(){
             count++;
             display.innerHTML = count;
             }
          </script>';

return $output;

}
add_shortcode('button-counter','btn_cntr_shortcode');
```